# How can I create a shimmer over time animation with a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

So I know most people don't prefer to have odd colors behind text but, my site http://www.cbradiowaves.com is supposed to look more like a newspaper. Anyways I'm using a canvas element to create a gradient for the background and it loads pretty quickly however I had this really cool idea that I could make the background appear to shimmer if I could only create a loop for the inputs to the canvas element settings. I think there will be an easy solution for an experienced javascript programmer.

Here's my code:

```
<canvas id="background" width="1020" height="1020"
style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("background");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// Create gradient
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,100,90,800,850);
grd.addColorStop(0,"white");
grd.addColorStop(1,"silver");

// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,1020,1020);
</script>
```

The line that needs to be incremented over time to create an animation is this one:

```
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,100,90,800,850);
```

I think that javascript has the power to do this probably with a function but it is escaping me.

Comment: could you specify/decribe how you want it to "shimmer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're wanting the shimmer effect to be something like a slow broad lens flare effect.

**Here's how...**

Create a radial gradient with 2 concentric circles inside an animation loop and animate the outer circle larger and smaller.

**The somewhat inefficient version.**

*Note: these demos are best viewed in the "Full Page" mode.*

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var offset=400;
var direction=4;

requestAnimationFrame(animate);


function animate(time){
  var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(cw/2,ch/2,100,cw/2,ch/2,offset);
  grd.addColorStop(0,"white");
  grd.addColorStop(1,"silver");
  ctx.fillStyle=grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  offset+=direction;
  if(offset<300 || offset>500){
    direction*=-1;
    offset+=direction;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

**The more efficient version if you've got a little extra memory:**

If you have the memory, you can create a second in-memory canvas with your radial gradient and drawImage the second canvas onto the visible canvas. Do drawImage in an animation loop and scale the drawing to create the shimmering pulse effect.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var scale=100;
var direction=1;

var c=document.createElement('canvas');
var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
var ccw=cw*1.50;
var cch=ch*1.50;
c.width=ccw;
c.height=cch;
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(ccw/2,cch/2,100,ccw/2,cch/2,500);
grd.addColorStop(0,"white");
grd.addColorStop(1,"silver");
cctx.fillStyle=grd;
cctx.fillRect(0,0,ccw,cch);

requestAnimationFrame(animate);


function animate(time){
  var iw=ccw*scale/100;
  var ih=cch*scale/100;
  ctx.drawImage(c,
                0,0,ccw,cch,
                cw/2-iw/2,ch/2-ih/2,iw,ih
               );
  scale+=direction;
  if(scale<75 || scale>125){
    direction*=-1;
    scale+=direction;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll toy around with it, I'm probably going to switch out the width and height being animated for the x and y so it will look more like light being moved crossing the page instead of changing size. Very helpful you are! Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just set your gradient as background of the element (I would suggest using a CSS gradient instead though) and then draw a white square on top with variable opacity (also here CSS opacity could have been used with animations).

This way the gradient is only rendered once, does not require an extra canvas buffer and the browser will do the main composition with the gradient.

Regulate speed and depth to suit your desire (I went for a subtle old-classic movie shimmer) - You could also save some performance by toggling the frame rate to 30 fps vs. default 60 fps.

## Canvas

```js
var c = document.getElementById("background"), ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// Create gradient
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(100,100,100,90,800,850);
grd.addColorStop(0,"white"); 
grd.addColorStop(1,"silver");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,1020,1020);

// Set as element background:
c.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + c.toDataURL() + ")";            // element bg.

ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";                                            // white fill

// variate opacity
(function loop(time) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);                          // clear frame
  ctx.globalAlpha = Math.abs(Math.sin(time * 0.008)) * 0.15 + 0.2; // set some opacity/time
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);                           // fill white
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
})(0);
```

```html
<canvas id="background" width="1020" height="1020"></canvas>
```

## A CSS version to consider:

Just a simple elliptic gradient here, adjust as needed:

```css
html, body, #background {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0}
#background {
  position:fixed;
  z-index:-1;
  /* note: you may need to add more prefixed version */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 2%,rgba(224,224,224,1) 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 2%,rgba(224,224,224,1) 100%);
  -webkit-animation: 0.2s shimmer linear infinite alternate;
  animation: 0.20s shimmer linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shimmer {from {opacity:0.8} to {opacity:1}}
@-webkit-keyframes shimmer {from {opacity:0.8} to {opacity:1}}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
```